# I have problem with switch command; I want to display something from case 1 in case 2

Tags: c#

I have `case 1` that ask you your name and age and then a `case 2` that show things asked in `case 1`
but the problem is since it thinks the user may or may not use `case 1` it says that my values are unassigned.
Is there anyway to fix this?

```
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

string Giname;
int Option, Gi, Q = 0, GiAge;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1-Get Info");
    Console.WriteLine("2-Show Info");
    Console.WriteLine("3-Show Trip Info");
    Console.WriteLine("4-Exit");
    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
    Console.Write("Choose you option : ");

    Option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.Clear();
    switch (Option)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your information");
            Console.Write("Passenger count : ");
            Gi = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            while (Gi > Q)
            {
                Q++;

                Console.Write("Enter your full name : ");
                Giname = (Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter your age : ");
                GiAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }// end while case 1

            Console.Clear();
            break;
            
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Count : {0} Person \n Name : {1} \n Age : {2} ", Gi, Giname, GiAge);
            break;

        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("-_-");
            break;

        case 4:
            break;
    } // end switch
} // end while

Console.ReadKey();
```

I tried using other commands such as `for`, `if` or moved the code out of `case 1` but that doesn't help.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen if the user picks option 2 without having previously picked option 1?

Comment: To make the program strong, I suggest you change Parse into TryParse

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of the warning, you should initialize the variables:

```
string Giname = "";
int Option, Gi = 0, Q = 0, GiAge = 0;
```

You should also report the missing information if the user selects option 2 without first selecting option 1:

```
        case 2:
            if (Q == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("first select option 1\n");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Count: {0} Person\n Name: {1}\n Age: {2}\n", Gi, Giname, GiAge);
            }
            break;
```